# Spring: order of creating initializing data with ApplicationRunner and Service initialization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

in my spring project i created some classes which provide me some initial base data in my development environment. These classes implement the `ApplicationRunner` interface and working fine.
After the container started the data is available.

What i noticed: I tried to create a new service with a constructor which autowires a data repository interface. When im trying to find a specific record which is part of my base data it can't be found.

According to my log i guess on container startup first all services are created and **after** the base data gets inserted.

Is there any chance to create some base or initial data before my `@Service` annotated class gets created or is this a kind of race condition?

Using spring boot + data with the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Service depends on some data being initialised, you should perhaps create the data in the constructor (or `afterPropertiesSet` method) of that service bean.

I mean, you have the `Repository` at your disposal (since it has just been wired in) so you could create the records you need at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You better create your initial data after the "ContxtRefreshedEvent".

you can do this by creating a class which implements "ApplicationListener" and insert your initial data inside  "onApplicationEvent" method

```
@Component
public class InitialDataLoader implements
ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
```

Sure you can Autowire your repositories and use them freely.